# Oracle SQL query to equally distribute tasks among people

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle database table 'table_1' having 2 columns with few sample rows as following-

```
CaseID    PerID
35039074    
36190822    
35067334    
36246430    
35239319    
36003875
```

Record in this dynamic table gets added frequently.

I have another oracle database table 'table_2' having 2 columns with following fixed number of rows-

```
Name    PerID
Nokia   8385
Opppo   7698
Vivo    5684
Mi      2351
```

I want to update the 'PerID' column of table_1 by taking the PerID (from table_2) and assign against each CaseID in table_1 in sequential way as following-

```
CaseID      PerID
35039074    8385
36190822    7698
35067334    5684
36246430    2351
35239319    8385
36003875    7698
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
with cte as
(select CaseID ,PerID 
from table_2)
update table_1 set perID=CTE.PerID where caseID=CTE.PerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the values by using `row_number()`:

```
with t1 as (
      select t1.*, rownum as seqnum
      from table_1 t1
     ),
     t2 as (
      select t2.*, rownum as seqnum, count(*) over () as cnt
      from table_2 t2
     ) t2
select t1.*, t2.perid
from table_1 t1 join
     table_2 t2
     on mod(t1.seqnum - 1, t2.cnt) = t2.seqnum;
```

If you need to actually update the value, then `merge` is probably the simplest approach.

```
merge into table_1 t1
    using (with t1 as (select t1.*, rownum as seqnum
                       from table_1 t1
                      ),
                      t2 as (
                       select t2.*, rownum as seqnum, count(*) over () as cnt
                       from table_2 t2
                      ) t2
                 select t1.*, t2.perid
                 from table_1 t1 join
                      table_2 t2
                      on mod(t1.seqnum - 1, t2.cnt) = t2.seqnum
                )
    on (s.caseid = t1.caseid)
when matched
    then update
        set t1.perID = s.perID;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff